# git push heroku master permission denied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I am following the ruby.railstutorial. I run the command "git push heroku master" and it spits out this error.

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I am inside my rails app "/Users/lexi87/rails_projects/first_app". Any solutions?

Comment: You may want to look at the Heroku guide for managing your SSH keys: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The best way to avoid such errors is to use one public/private key pair and not an extra key for heroku. This way you (or your system) can't choose a wrong key to login in heroku.

If you get this error, you have done something wrong. Check this site: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys

If you geht this error, the best way is to remove unnecessary keys and use only one.

If you need more than one key pair on your system, you can set one key for heroku. This is done through the following command:

```
heroku keys:add
```

Comment: Thank you. I had to run the command heroku keys:add and then select the id_rsa option.

Answer (score 13):

Some help for Windows 7 users with Github Windows client installed:

Even though heroku toolbelt reports it found my git_hub public key and uploaded it, 'git push heroku master' failed.  After taking the steps below, it works fine.

1. Create .ssh folder under your User folder if one does not exist.  If
   it does, delete all files in it (this assumes you are OK with starting from scratch with ssh keys).
2. In Windows Explorer, right click the
   .ssh folder, and choose Git bash from the context menu. This is installed along with the Github Windows client software.
3. In the bash window enter
   `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "yourname@email.com`"  When prompted enter a
   passphrase (don't lose this).
4. Close the bash shell window.
5. From a cmd prompt in your project's root, enter `heroku keys:add`. 
   This will find and upload the key you just created from your /.ssh file to
   Heroku.

Now you can enter `git push heroku master` to push you app up to Heroku. 
Note: you will need to add your newly generated ssh public key to your Github account when done.

Comment: perfect @mjulmer. Tried a lot of options but at last your solution worked for me. Thanks a lot. This is for Windows 7 users of course :)

Comment: also i think the major difference with your method and what I was trying is the '-C emailaddress' attribute. my case it was taking the windows username as windows@windows-PC instead of my email address registered with you heroku. Again not sure if that is really the reason :)

Comment: thanks! I was going in circles with the other answers for non-windows

Comment: Perfect ! * It says I need to write 6 more characters! *

Comment: @mjulmer Windows Explorer on windows 10 doesnt allow to create ".ssh" . In  Commant Prompt window(console) you can create the folder  with "mkdir  .ssh" instead

Answer (score 8):

I faced the same issue. In my .ssh folder I had a file called 'Known Hosts'. I kept trying to delete and create new ssh keys it did not work. In the end I just deleted everything in .ssh including 'Known Hosts' and then created a new rsa key using:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

then I added this new key to heroku using:

```
heroku keys:add
```

then create a new heroku repo and pushed my app to it:

```
heroku create
git push heroku master
```

Answer (score 4):

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

Above is optional as you could also link to an existing key.   Heroku will prompt to select the key in the next step.

```
heroku keys:add
```

Add your newly created key or an existing one.  If you are still running into the issue, you will most likely need to add the key to your machine's list of ssh keys by performing the following:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/name_of_your_rsa
```

and confirm that your ssh has been added

```
ssh-add -l
```

This should get you access to push to Heroku's remote repo.

Answer (score 2):

on OSX, I was having experiencing the same issue, I was getting

```
no such identity: /Users/me/.ssh/yourPrivateKey: No such file or directory
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I tried to create a new key with ssh-keygen -t rsa then adding it with heroku keys:add, but it didn't help.

Then I found a file named *config* in ~/.ssh/, and inside the file there was:

```
ServerAliveInterval 300
ServerAliveCountMax 3

host heroku.com
    user git
    hostname heroku.com
    identityfile ~/.ssh/yourPrivateKey
```

So I changed *yourPrivateKey* to my private key filename (*id_rsa* by default) aaand it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

I created a key with

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

and used a different filename than id_rsa (in my case heroku). I added the key to heroku with

```
heroku keys:add
```

On trying to push my master branch to heroku I always received the following error:

> **$ git push heroku master**
>   The authenticity of host 'heroku.com
>   (50.19.85.132)' can't be established. RSA key fingerprint is
>   8b:48:5e:67:0e:c9:16:47:32:99:87:0c:1f:c8:60:bb. Are you sure you want
>   to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes Warning: Permanently added
>   'heroku.com,50.19.85.132' (RSA) to the list of known hosts. Permission
>   denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository 
>   exists.

As I noticed git only used my id_rsa key from another ssh-access (you can check that via your git gui: Help -> SSH keys).

I renamed my .ssh directory *C:\Users\%username%.ssh* to *.ssh.bak* and copied my *heroku* private and public key (from the *.ssh.bak* directory) to a newly created *.ssh* directory and named it id_rsa (and id_rsa.pub).

Now pushing worked as expected:

```
git push heroku master
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on Windows, be sure to use **git-bash** instead of Powershell/Command Prompt.

If you just want to reset your ssh keys:

1. delete your user's .ssh dir
2. open git-bash
3. ssh-keygen -t rsa
4. heroku keys:add

and then you will be able to git push.